# How do I include angular app in external html file

Tags: angular, angular7, web-component, angular-elements

I'm using Angular 7 and I want to insert the angular app as a widget in another external html file.

I know there are angular elements to create a custom element and insert it but having many browser compatibility issues in that. I tried including the `<app-root></app-root>` in the external html and added the scripts and it is working fine in all browsers. But I'm unable to pass inputs to the root element.

Is this right way to include my angular app in external file. And also how to pass input to the root component.

Comment: are you talking about the whole app or just one component?

Comment: like how we associate it with custom elements

Comment: is it fine if we use the app-root directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export a certain component as a web component, you can use angular elements, as you said. Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

If you would like to include the whole website inside yours, you can use an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).